# laravel redirection to splash page during testing

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

I've spent too many hours messing with this

I'm just starting with laravel and started a new project.
I want to be able to have a system where a certain users can access the site while it is in development. The rest of the public gets forwarded to the splash page.
I plan to create a secret route that sets a toggle in the session. If this toggle is set then the user can use the entire system. Else they are redirected to the splash page.

The issue is I cannot get it to redirect. I have been adding the code in the bootstrap->start.php file. The standard

```
header('location:www.thesite.com')
```

starts doing funny things that I do not understand.

If I run

```
return Redirect::to(htmlspecialchars_decode($url))
```

it returns the error:

```
BadMethodCallException

Method [run] does not exist on Redirect.
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on or how to fix it.
Why is the redirection script returning an error? Is start.php not the correct location?
If so how can achieve my objective within laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in your `before` filter in `app/filters.php` like so:

```
App::before(function($request){

    if(!$request->is('splash') && Input::get('allow') != '1')
    {
         return Redirect::to('/splash');
    }

);
```

Where `/splash` is your splash screen route. You can then do `http://www.example.com?allow=1` to bypass the splash screen.

The `before` filter is a function that is run before every single route in your application.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks. Moving the code to the filters.php did the job. I did not use your code. The splash page is completely separate from laravel. It is already working. I do not want to confused it. I just redirect the user. It works fine however the only issues is the URL in the address bar vanishes. I'm guess laravel is doing this. Not that I know how or why.

Comment: What do you mean by making the URL in the address bar vanish?

Comment: Exactly that. Nothing the address bar. On live it seems not to be an issues. I'm guess it is unrelated at this stage. I have not spent time debugging it for now. More important things are pressing. Looks like something to do with the redirection. I'll spend time on it later.